# Verify Email And Form Entry With Script

Tags: javascript, php

I have a script that I have been using for a few years and it works on everything I use it on. It seems to be broken all of a sudden on a new script I am using it on.

I need for it to check that First Name was filled out and that the email address entered is a Gmail email address only.

I am hoping that someone can look at the code and let me know if I am missing something, or show me a better way to do this.

Here is my code:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="putform3.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<div class='card-img-top' style="position: relative; width: 300px; padding: 5px; background-color: #989eae;"><center>
<b>Fill Out The Form Below</b><br />
<input class='card-img-top' name="fname" type="text" value="" style="width:280px; margin-bottom:5px; color:#000000;" placeholder="First Name" required /><br />
<input class='card-img-top' name="email" type="text" value="" style="width:280px; margin-bottom:5px; color:#000000;" placeholder="Gmail Email" required /><br />

<input type="hidden" name="affiliate" value="$affiliate" />
<input type="hidden" name="myip" value="$ip" />
<input type="hidden" name="lp" value="$lp" />
<input class="formbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="$buttontext"><br />
<span style="font-size: 10px;">We keep your information private!</span>
</center></div>
</from>


<script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var e=document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
var f=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
var atpos=e.indexOf("@");
var dotpos=e.lastIndexOf(".");
var gmail = e.split("@");
var rgmail = gmail[1];
if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=e.length)
  {
  alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
  return false;
  }
if (rgmail == "yahoo.com" || rgmail == "hotmail.com" || rgmail == "msn.com" || rgmail == "aol.com" || rgmail == "yandex.com")
    {
  alert("Must Be A Good gmail.com Email Address");
  return false;
    }

if (f==null || f=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

The javascript is totally being ignored. It's not that it's not working but it's never being used. I am totally lost here as it works on all my other scripts. I even put an `alert('worked');` in the script to be sure it was being used and it's not showing the alert.

Comment: check your browser console, is there any js error?

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox. You should really use a RegEx for the email check though.

Comment: yeah it is working fine, in my local too There might be other js issue on your page which stops js to run.

Btw your `rgmail` condition is not correct, it should be `if (rgmail != "gmail.com")`

Comment: I tried that `if (rgmail != "gmail.com")` and it never seemed to work lol. Anyway I will try it again when I get this working.

Comment: I used Chrome and did the inspect and the only caution showing is this.... [Deprecation] "zoom: reset" is deprecated and will be removed in M59, around June 2017. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4997605029314560 for more details.  I can't find a `zoom: reset` in any of my code.

Comment: your form end must be `</form>` rather than `</from>`

Comment: Ok fixed the typo lol but that did not make it work. If there was a way to give out the page url here I would just let you go to the page because maybe I am linking to something that's causing it to not work. Can I put a URL in here? I think it will block me if I do.

Comment: you can put your webpage link here

Comment: Please don't worry about the style of the page, it's made to work on a cell phone only lol. https://gmpbtl.com/lp/index.php?i=20 You can see that you can just press the button with nothing in it and it goes to the php script. It should bring up the alert and say "You must enter in your first name" So that means the whole script is being ignored for some reason.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145495/discussion-between-mahesh-singh-chouhan-and-randy-thomas).

Comment: the code is work but no `gmail.com` in `if (rgmail == "yahoo.com" || rgmail == "hotmail.com" || rgmail == "msn.com" || rgmail == "aol.com" || rgmail == "yandex.com")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the website link provided:

There were multiple js issues on [website](https://gmpbtl.com/lp/index.php?i=20) which causes js validation function to run properly are:

> 1. use `https:` instead of `http` for jquery file include url
> 2. inside `script.js` file `window.getComputedStyle` is undefined
> 3. remove additional `lname` value line inside validation function as
>              there is no such input in the form

Comment: I can't believe I overlooked those 3 things. Thank you. That worked perfectly.